# Cannot read field 'user_properties' of type STRUCT as STRING when querying with _TABLE_SUFFIX

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm querying against a BigQuery dataset that is exported from Firebase, using Standard SQL. I'm getting `Cannot read field 'user_properties' of type STRUCT as STRING` whenever I use a wildcard query with a conditional `_TABLE_SUFFIX`, but works when I don't use wildcard query.

```
SELECT
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS suffix,
  user_properties
FROM 
  `analytics_<firebase_id>.events_*`
WHERE 
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20191026'
  AND 
  app_info.id = '<my_app_id>'
```

Got error
`Cannot read field 'user_properties' of type STRUCT as STRING`

If I change my query to

```
SELECT
  user_properties
FROM 
  `analytics_<firebase_id>.events_20191026`
WHERE 
  app_info.id = '<my_app_id>'
```

It returns expected results.

And a sanity check

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(_TABLE_SUFFIX) AS suffix
FROM 
  `analytics_<firebase_id>.events_*`
WHERE 
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20191026'
  AND 
  app_info.id = '<my_app_id>'
```

It returns "20191026" as expected.

I can't understand why using wildcard can result in a different type of `user_properties`. This also happened to me before and it just worked when I retried after couple hours. I highly suspect this is a BigQuery bug, but their support brings me here.

(The reason I have to use _TABLE_SUFFIX is that I need to pass the date as a parameter. In my actual code it is `_TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(DATE(@run_time), INTERVAL 1 DAY))` for ETL jobs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When [Wildcard Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference) used - BigQuery engine first identifies the very earliest created object that matches wildcard and using that object to identify the schema. And only then - using that schema - matched tables are being queried.

So my guess about what most likely happening for you - you have earlier table or view that matches `analytics_<firebase_id>.events_*` which has field `user_properties` as type STRING - while in `analytics_<firebase_id>.events_20191026` this field is of type STRUCT

You need to make sure that all objects matching your wildcard have same schema to not to have issues like this

To test this, just run below as an example

```
SELECT
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS suffix,
  user_properties
FROM 
  `analytics_<firebase_id>.events_201910*`
WHERE 
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = '26'
  AND 
  app_info.id = '<my_app_id>'
```

Comment: You're right. It turns out I did have some weird table names that could match events_*. If I change it to `201910*` it works. Thanks!